# Baron is to Barony as Earl is to what?

Tags: middle-ages

A simple question really. I'm trying to find a word and my Google-fu has failed me.

- Baron is to Barony
- Duke is to Duchy
- Earl is to what?

Comment: FWIW, I think the question is on topic. Simple, but not trivial. If you don't know the term, it is very difficult to search for it, and for obvious reasons, "Earldom" doesn't follow modern English inflection patterns.  I believe we could add the "England" tag, because I don't think there are Earldoms anywhere else?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace [Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earldoms#Earldoms_in_the_Peerage_of_Scotland.2C_1072.E2.80.931707) and [Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earldoms#Earldoms_in_the_Peerage_of_Ireland.2C_1205.E2.80.931831) had their own Earldoms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an earldom.

You can see here a list of them:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earldoms

Comment: Note that it may also be a county; as the English *earl* is equivalent to the European *count*. Hence a *vice-count*, or *viscount*, is one noble rank below *earl* in the English peerage.

Comment: And a female Earl is referred to as a Countess.